# Setting color of curve in octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have two column of data and would like to plot using octave. I did following :

```
 f = load('rate.txt','r')
 plot(f(:,1) ,f(:,2));
 plot(f(:,1));
 hold on;
 plot(f(:,2));
```

I got respective graph. But both are in same color. I would like to assign differnet color for different graph and name to them like this colored graph is of this and this colored graph is of that. How would i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw hem using the [line properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linespec.html). And [`legend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html) is for stating which one is what. I suppose that Octave uses the same syntax as MATLAB. Here's an example code snippet:

```
x = 0:0.01:5; %# An example x grid

plot(x,sin(x),'r-');
hold on;
plot(x,cos(x),'b--');
legend('sin', 'cos')
```

[image]